# Multiplying a variable by number inside a console.log on javascript

Tags: javascript

I wish I could log to the console the result of a multiplication of a number by a variable but I get NaN as a result while using Javascript.

My attempt:

```
var div = Number(console.log(10 / 50)); //returns 0.2
typeof div //number
console.log(div * 100); //returns NaN
```

I also tried

```
var div = Number(console.log(10 / 50)); //returns 0.2
typeof div //number
console.log(Number(div) * 100); //returns NaN
```

Why is it happening and how should I avoid it?

Comment: You could define your own function `tap = x => (console.log(x), x)` and use it instead of console.log `var div = Number(tap(10 / 50));`

Comment: Thanks, but what I was looking for required me to log a step by step result. That solution would give me only the final result.

Comment: It will give whatever result you use this function on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `console.log()` function returns undefined, so `Number(console.log(anything))` will always be `NaN`. Your code assumes that `console.log()` returns the value that it wrote to the browser developer console, but that is not the case.

Also, probably counter intuitively, `NaN` is a number, so `typeof NaN` is "number". Your code tested the return value from `Number(console.log())` and it was in fact a number, but that number is `NaN`.

Answer (score 2):

`console.log` **only** display the result and returns **undefined**.

Try directly:

```
 var div = Number(10 / 50);
```

```js
var div = Number(10 / 50); //returns 0.2
typeof div //number
console.log(div * 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` does not return a number, and so you get a `NaN` error.

You can instead do:

```js
var div = Number(10 / 50);
console.log(div * 100);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It answers how I can avoid it in a simple, straightforward way.

Answer (score 0):

A small workaround:

```
 function log(...values){
  console.log(...values);
  return values.length === 1 ? values[0] : values;
}
```

So you can do:

```
var a = log(5/10)*2;
log(a);
log(log(1,2)[0]+3)
```

---

Alternatively, do it the other way round:

```
 var a;

console.log(
  a = 10/50,
  10*a,
  11*a
);
```